# Create / access an Account collection in accounts-base?

Tags: meteor

I'm following a tutorial (3.4 Accounts on tuts+) and am unsure why I am getting an undefined error when attempting Accounts.createUser()

The error is suggesting that I must first create a collection as createUser() isn't recognised.

The code is here

http://meteorpad.com/pad/fbc4TQpB3EWEjDMGQ

Recreate the error by clicking the [Create Account] button, and then fill out the form and [Create]

According to the code, it should create a record in the Accounts collection but it doesn't.

I'm wondering if this tutorial was written for a legacy version of accounts-base

The tutorial episode is here

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6707713/10-accounts.mov

Thanks

Jon

Comment: You haven't added package `accounts-password`.

Comment: That's done the trick thanks. The video had made out like it should be removed. Thanks.